# Algorithm to eliminate negative amounts from a map and sum with other positive amounts

Tags: java, algorithm, groovy

I have a map (key/value pair) like this `[key1:25, key2:20, key3:-30, key4:10, key5:-5]`. Now, I need to eliminate all the entries where amount is negative, and have those amounts subtracted from other entries with positive amounts:

So this would be a valid map : `[key1:20, key2:0, key4:0]`

So, is there any better solution then iterating over entire map and summing with positive amounts, for every negative amount.

Eventually at the end, I will need to remove the entries with amount 0 too.. but that's fine, I can iterate over the full map once and remove those with 0's

Comment: sounds like a good java8 test.

Comment: How do you get from `[key1:25, key2:20, key3:-30, key4:10, key5:-5]` to `[key1:20, key2:0, key4:0]`?

Comment: @tim_yates you didn't get the [key1:key1+key5,key2:key2+key3-key4,key4:key1-key5-key2+key3+key4+key2-key4] ? :-p

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : No.
Given that there is **no restriction** on the map, there is no better way than brute force.
Even if you look for a language specific trick, **behind the scene** it should use **exhaustive** search.

Note that cycling over the map is in **O(n)** so even if you want to sort it or convert the map to something like `TreeMap` it would take more that **O(n)**.

Answer (score 0):

the way i see your problem you have to just add them all and put the result in a map. You dont need to save it to same map either.

```
Map<String, Integer> outputMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int output = 0; 
for(Integer valinMap: inputMap) { 
   output += valinMap; 
}
outputMap.put("key1", output);
```

Please mention if your requirement is different.

Comment: I dont want to sum them all. I just need to eliminate the negative values by summing them up with positive values. Your solution seems to sum all the values under a single key